# Google Website Optimizer Two onClick Events?

Tags: javascript, magento, google-analytics, onclick, dom-events

There are plenty of answers online for 'how to combine two onclick events' but nothing seems to work in my situation. Google Website Optimizer gives a tutorial on tracking an event, such as a click. First, I add this to my Analytics code:

```
  function doGoal(that) { 
    try {
```

And so on. Then, I should add the following to my event:

```
onclick="doGoal(this);return false;"
```

But my event is a button that already contains an onclick event:

```
<input type="image" src="image.png" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this);return false;">
```

How do I combine the two? Anything I've tried has either registered nothing with Google, or will forward me to a page called '/undefined/'

Answer (score 1):

When you want to bind the same event to multiple things you should use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).
Bear in mind that in IE8 and anything before you need to use attachEvent. (also mentioned in above documentation)

Alternatively

```
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this);doGoal(this);return false;"
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to track so I will use an event and pageview as an example:

```
function doGoal() {
    var productNum = document.productAddToCartForm.product.value;
    var productQty = document.productAddToCartForm.qty.value;
    //event tracking
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cart', 'Add', productNum,  productQty]);
    //virtual page tracking for goal
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/cart/add/']);
    setTimeout("document.productAddToCartForm.submit()", 100);
}
```

Image button:

```
<input type="image" src="image.png" onclick="doGoal();return false;">
```

[Event tracking guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)

These are examples. Put your own values in the tracking that you would like.

The `setTimeout` function allows the trackers time to be sent before the form processes.

Simple fiddle example without the analytics tracking: http://jsfiddle.net/4vvKv/2/